# "Parse error" in struct declaration

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I want to use some basic struct in C like the following:

```
struct p {
    int a;
    int b;
    p * next;
}
```

However, it fails to compile with an `error: parse error before "p"` on the line with `p * next;`.

Do you have any idea what the reason could be for this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C structs live in a different namespace and have to be explicitly scoped, thus:

```
struct p {
    int a;
    int b;
    struct p * next;
};
```

And don't forget the semicolon at the end! :-)

You can pretend you're in C++ thus: `typedef struct p { /*...*/ } p;`. But I think that `next` will still have be declared as above.

Comment: You are right that `struct p* next;` is still needed with typedef, because the typedef'd name *p* isn't yet in scope.